# organizing custom javascripts in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I'm new to mvc 4 and I'm wondering where I should put my custom javascript files. By 'custom', I mean scripts that are only used in specific Views or PartialViews.

I use Areas too, so that adds up the complexity. I was thinking about placing my scripts in the Script folder at the root of the application and then in a Custom sub-folder.

How would I then reference the scripts in my Views ? Should I use custom Bundles ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

i think that adding your scripts to a custom folder in your `scripts` folder is the way to go.
you can create a new bundle in the `appstart\BundleConfig.cs` file as follows:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/Custom/myCustom.js",
                   "~/Scripts/Custom/myCustom2.js"));
```

and than add the `bundle` to your view like this:

```
@section scripts{

 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")

}
```

this will be rendered at the `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` line on your `layout` file.

**OR**
To call only one specific `script` for your `view` you can do:

```
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/myCustom.js"></script>
}
```

note: you can drag the script file from the `solution explorer` into the section. you don't have to write the entire path.
**EDIT**  - seems important so i copied this from my last comment:
 in order to use `minification` you need to add your script to the bundle table and either add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` to the `BundleConfig` file or set `<compilation debug="false"` in your `web.config` file.

Comment: thanks. I just have one problem with this approach: obviously one is likely to load only one View at a time, with one associated custom script. With a scriptbundle, I would be loading ALL of the custom scripts for every Views whenever I browse to a View. That seems overkill to me, let alone the risk of conflict between scripts (e.g: my custom scripts usually start with $(document).ready)

Comment: not sure if i understand your question. the bundle defined at the `scripts section` will be rendered only for the view that called it. also there is no problem calling `(document).ready()` multiple times, see [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_$%28document%29.ready%28%29).

Comment: what I meant is that if I create one bundle for all of my custom scripts, then whenever a View calls this bundle all of my custom scripts will be loaded. So I was wondering if instead I should create one bundle per custom script.

Comment: if you only need to load one script then you don't need to create a bundle for it, just call the specific script in the scripts section on your view (see my edited answer).

Comment: yes, that's what I do at the moment. But then I don't take advantage of optimization (minifying in particular).

Comment: you are correct. in order for to use the `minification` you need to add your script to the `bundle table` and either add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` to the `BundleConfig` file or set `<compilation debug="false" ...` in your `web.config` file.

Answer (score 2):

You could organize your scripts in the `Scripts` folder:

- ~/Scripts/Home/foobar.js
- ~/Scripts/Admin/baz.js
- ...

> Should I use custom Bundles ?

Sure, you could bundle the scripts that always go together.

Comment: often, I only have one script per View. Would that be ok to create one bundle per unique script ? Is this not too much  ?

Comment: Minifying should be enough. Also you might consider grouping functionality in one larger script that is reused between the views. It's much better to have one single minified bundle, even if not all the functionality is being used in a given view, rather than having hundreds of small scripts for each view.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Isn't it better to create bundles per view? Then they can be merged and have only one or few scripts per View.