# How do I add scripts to the bundle in a CSHTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form, that form has it's own script, I want to add a script to the bundle if that form is included somewhere. I want to do this from the CSHTML of this form.

Basically I want this:

```
<form>
 ... code here
</form>
@includemyscript formscript.js
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621988/organizing-custom-javascripts-in-asp-net-mvc-4/14622193#14622193) might help you

Answer (score 1):

That is not how bundles work. You can create a new bundle containing all scripts plus your form script and render that one on this specific page, or just use the default bundle and additionally reference your script by a `<script></script>` tag.