# My js in the Scripts folder are not being loaded in my MVC4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 scripts.  One is in a Folder called ItemMenu in the root and the other is in the Scripts folder that is also in the root.

The script in the Scripts folder is never loaded, but the ItemMenu one it. They are both included in a script tag the same way on the client.

Here is the HTML render of the scripts.

```
<script src="/Scripts/article_layout1.js"></script>
<script src="/ItemMenu/itemMenu.js"></script>
```

If, I use the full URL it will work - but this won't work long term.

It's not making any sense to me.

I have confirmed the locations of these and "/Scripts/article_layout1.js" can be accessed by navigating directly to the URL.  I have confirmed the spelling and folder names.

Does anyone have any idea here?  This is going to make me crazy maybe.

Comment: Which approach do you use to add js file to app view? with bundleconfig or?

Comment: "Here is the HTML render of the scripts." where?

Comment: I just add it as a script tag in the view and it renders in the script section.  I showed you what is being rendered.  That's what is important.

Comment: It just wont load the script file even though I have used a forward slash to indicate to start at the root.  It isn't clear to me how "/Script/file" does not work, but "hxxp://rootURL/Script/file" does work.  Don't browsers interpret this as the same thing assuming rootURL is the rootURL host of the site....

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621988/organizing-custom-javascripts-in-asp-net-mvc-4/14622193#14622193). it shows how to use a add scripts in a `bundle` or without it

Comment: Yes.  But, this won't help me.  I add "/Scripts/article_layout1.js" to a bundle and render the bundle, it's going to have the same problem since it doesn't recognize "/" root on some of my js files but works for others.  Weird.

Comment: Maybe a bundle will include the host url, but that's still a work around.  This is basic browser technology that isn't working on any browser.  It's weird.  Unless CASINI is being a dick about things...

Comment: try to drag and drop the `script file` from `solution explorer` to your code and see if it works.

Comment: Nope.  Didn't work.  This is messed.

Comment: try this: `<script src="~/ItemMenu/itemMenu.js"></script>` instead of this: `<script src="/ItemMenu/itemMenu.js"></script>`. notice the `~` sign.

Comment: Noticed.  Something I tried already.  Doesn't work.  So weird.

Comment: Ok, so I figured it out.  So, just above the script tag that wasn't working was this little diddy..  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"/> - self closing script tag which the browsers didn't recognize, so it was screwing up the next script tag after it.  Yeesh...  didn't see that until a few mins ago...